# Drawing a double and showing the decimal places?

Tags: c#, double, decimal

```
public class ExperienceTable
{
    public static int MaxExperiencePoints;
    public static double PercentToNextLevel;

    public static void checkLevel(Hero player)
    {
        if (player.ExperiencePoints >= 0)
        {
            player.Level = 1;
            MaxExperiencePoints = 15;
            PercentToNextLevel = player.ExperiencePoints / MaxExperiencePoints;
        }
    }
```

Then drawing it to the screen using:

```
        GameRef.SpriteBatch.DrawString(GUIFont, "" + ExperienceTable.PercentToNextLevel, new Vector2((int)player.Camera.Position.X + 1200, (int)player.Camera.Position.Y + 676), Color.White);
```

How come decimal places don't show up? Seems like the numbers are being rounded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, the decimal place will not be shown if the double is already a rounded number in the first place. I'm guessing `player.ExperiencePoints` is an `int`. And `int` divided by another `int` will always result to an `int`, resulting in a rounded value.

Assuming that `player.ExperiencePoints` is really an `int`, and you want to have the fraction when dividing it, you should change the division line to the following:

```
PercentToNextLevel = (double) player.ExperiencePoints / MaxExperiencePoints;
```

And if you want to have the decimal places displayed eventhough it's `.00`, then  change the `ExperienceTable.PercentToNextLevel` to something like the following.

```
ExperienceTable.PercentToNextLevel.ToString("0.00")
```

`.ToString("0.00")` will convert the double value to a string with 2 decimal places, and will round it to two decimal places if it have to.

Answer (score 1):

I think

```
PercentToNextLevel = player.ExperiencePoints / MaxExperiencePoints;
```

is an integer division (that's if `player.ExperiencePoints` is an integer).

Try that:

```
PercentToNextLevel = (double)player.ExperiencePoints / MaxExperiencePoints;
```

Answer (score 0):

If `player.ExperiencePoints` is also an `int`, then you are dividing an integer by an integer, and the result is a rounded integer. Instead, use

```
PercentToNextLevel = (double)player.ExperiencePoints / MaxExperiencePoints
```